# When I start the workflow, nothing happen in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

[image]When I start the workflow nothing happen not even state of workflow showing like Completed or canceled? What the issue ? It happen only for specific workflow, When i create new workflow for same list it work.

Comment: I have one doubt is anything permission issue? because when i create new work flow its work.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because your workflows are not triggering so you can open services.msc and restart the SharePoint time job services

Comment: It happen only for specific workflow, When i create new workflow for same list it work.

Comment: can you please share the screen shot of your workflow ?

Comment: Please check  attachment. Newworkflow is not started.

Comment: Can i share my workflow logic screen shot?

Comment: have you manually tried running your workflow ?

Comment: Yes i set 3 option for start workflow, Created,manually and change.

Comment: share your workflow logic

Comment: Hey logic is very simple please check http://prnt.sc/ccgwc0   in workflow there is no any error. I create the log history but not showing anything. this work flow not start. i do many thing but not get success to this workflow. when create new workflow its work but i want to use this workflow.